# How to tail and grep log file, combine into a single line and pass as argument to another command

Tags: grep, tail

Using the following command, I managed to fetch error messages below (it's 3 lines).

```
$ tail -f -n 0 error.log | grep -A2 --line-buffered "Internal server error"
! @79884flo2 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[Missing: No configuration setting found for key init.default]
```

Tried few technique to combine the logs into a single line and successful:

1. `xargs`

   ```
   tail -f -n 0 error.log | grep -A2 --line-buffered "error" | xargs -I @ printf "%s" "@"
   ```
2. `awk`

   ```
   tail -f -n 0 error.log | grep -A2 --line-buffered "error" | awk '{ printf("%s ", $0); }'
   ```
3. `paste`:

   ```
   tail -f -n 0 error.log | grep -A2 --line-buffered "error" | paste -d " " - - -
   ```

Next I want to send the output to telegram using `telegram-notify` command:

```
telegram-notify --error --title "<title>" --text "<output from above command goes here>"
```

The best I can do at the moment is to send each line of the logs separately using `xargs` to telegram.

```
tail -f -n 0 error.log | grep -A2 --line-buffered "error" | xargs -L 3 -I {} telegram-notify --error --title "<title>" --text "{}"
```

Would you please advise:

1. Which command among the three `xargs`, `awk`, `paste` I've tried above should be used to combined lines?
2. How to pipe further or pass output from the `xargs`/`awk`/`paste` to the `telegram-notify` command `--text` option

Comment: Did you try putting another xargs in front of the existing xargs - `tail -f -n 0 error.log | grep -A2 --line-buffered "error" | xargs -I @ printf "%s" "@" | xargs -L 3 -I {} telegram-notify --error --title "" --text "{}"`  ? Does that meet your purpose ?

Comment: @amisax Yes I did and it didn't work. Didn't see any tail output and telegram-notify is not triggered